# Создание фильтров изображения

Tags: delphi

Подскажите сайт, где подробно бы описывалось создание фильтров изображения.

Хотелось бы не просто исходники, а именно объяснение алгоритмов. Может есть какая-нибудь литература на этот счёт?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ищите книги по СОМД (Системы обработки мультимедиа данных) в них обычно есть фильтры и переход к фильтрации изображений (например медианный фильтр).

Думаю, что для начала надо понять сам принцип фильтрации, чтобы предпринимать шаги к написанию или хотя бы пониманию того, что делает конкретный фильтр с изображением и почему.